# BackgroundTransferRequest providing file as post parameter

Tags: file-upload, windows-phone-8, background-transfer

A website accepts POST file uploads where file data should be provided as a parameter, like so: http://website.com?act=upload&file=[file data]

How can I use `BackgroundTransferRequest` in Windows Phone 8 to upload a file from my IsolatedStorage to this website?

All the tutorials I've encountered so far just use some generic upload URI (something like http://website.com/upload/ without parameters) in combination with  `BTS.UploadLocation = [Uri to file]; BackgroundTransferService.Add(BTS);` But in my case I need to somehow bind file data with `file` POST parameter.

Comment: Sorry, this does not make sense. Either the upload is done as http POST *or* as http GET with url parameters. You cannot have both.

Comment: @arkascha maybe I'm getting it wrong but here's an excerpt from website that explains upload process: 2. The application forms POST request for the received URL. The request shall include *photo* field containing a file with an image (JPG, PNG, BMP or GIF)

Comment: That might well be. But then the parameters are coded as POST parameters, unlike what you suggested in your question (as GET parameters). I suggest you learn about the difference and edit your question to get a reply.

Comment: @arkascha OK. I'm using GET-style to just illustrate my point that I need to use a *photo* parameter in my BackgroundTransferRequest. If you could suggest a better illustration I'd gladly include it in my question.

Comment: Well, I don't see what has to be illustrated here... You want to make a POST request using that `BackgroundTransferRequest` thing (I do not know). The POST should hold two parameters: a scalar 'act' with value 'upload' and a file parameter 'file' holding the content of a file to be uploaded.

Comment: @arkascha `BackgroundTransferRequest` is a service that lets file uploads while mobile application is closed. This is a question about it's API really. I'm sure winphone programmers will understand what I'm asking for.

Comment: @arkascha I think you're wrong. What you're referring to as "url parameters" or "GET parameters" are defined in [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) as the _query component_, and it's a valid part of a URI. I can't find anything in [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) which forbids certain combinations of valid URIs and request methods (such as GET and POST). What you're referring to as "POST parameters" is called the _message-body_, and that is not permitted with every kind of method. If you still disagree, please direct me to something which backs up your claim.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use below Code:

Just call Upload function and pass parameters like "xyz.png", file byte[], your server URL.
other things remain same..
you will get response in response function.
in my case i receive uploaded file url.
its working for me.
hope for you too.
good luck.

```
public void Upload(string name, byte[] content, String uriStr)
        {
            string boundary = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string header = "--" + boundary;
            string footer = "--" + boundary + "--";

            HttpWebRequest uploadRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriStr);
            uploadRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
            uploadRequest.Method = "POST";

            StringBuilder headers = new StringBuilder();
            headers.AppendLine(header);
            headers.AppendLine("Content-Disposition: file; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + name + "\"");
            headers.AppendLine("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
            headers.AppendLine();
            headers.AppendLine(Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(content, 0, content.Length));
            headers.AppendLine(footer);
            Console.Write(headers.ToString());

            byte[] contents = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(headers.ToString());
            object[] data = new object[2] { uploadRequest, contents };
            uploadRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetData), data);
        }


public void GetData(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            object[] data = (object[])result.AsyncState;
            byte[] content = (byte[])data[1];

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)data[0];
            Stream requestStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(result);
            int start = 0, count = 1024;

            while (true)
            {
                if (start + count > content.Length)
                {
                    requestStream.Write(content, start, (content.Length - start));
                    break;
                }
                requestStream.Write(content, start, count);
                start += count;
            }

            requestStream.Close();
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponse), request);
        }

public void GetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            string imageUploadedUrl = "";

            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        string check = line.Substring(0, 9);
                        if (check == "    <Url>")
                        {
                            imageUploadedUrl = line.Substring(9, (line.Length - 15));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: As far as I see this code does not employ `BackgroundTransferRequest` but uses `HttpWebRequest` instead. Well, that's an option if it can't be done with BTS. Ability to upload files while application is closed is important for me.

Comment: ohhh...sorry for that.
But i have implemented HttpWebRequest.